# Getting the destination Point from ItemDragEventArgs in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

How does one get the destination point from `ItemDragEventArgs`? With `Microsoft.Windows.DragEventArgs e` it is easy: `e.GetPosition(<UIElement to which the point is relative to>)`

**XAML**

```
<toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True" ItemDroppedOnTarget="DragAndDrop_ItemDroppedOnTarget">
```

**Code behind**

```
private void DragAndDrop_ItemDroppedOnTarget(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
   // how to get the destination Point here??
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a hack, but it worked and is pretty accurate:

```
private Point _releasePoint;

public Grid()
{
   Grid.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp);
}

void Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   _releasePoint = e.GetPosition(Grid);
}

private void DragAndDrop_ItemDroppedOnTarget(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
   // fires next and _releasePoint is already set
}
```